# set phone background image from gallery

Tags: android, background-image, android-gallery

I want to open image from galley and then set that image as phone background. I am able to open the gallery but getting error while setting that image as phone background.

Comment: @Fahim i am getting the gallery image uri but while setting the background I uses          Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id );      instead of id what should i use

Comment: Check my edited answer. Please provide the full code in order to check it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the image from the imageUri and save it as a bitmap object. Make sure you have the Set Wallpaper permission in the Android Manifest.

```
Bitmap image =MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);

WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```